# How to change default Bootstrap color with CSS style property?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made this navigation-bar with **bootstrap** and I want to change its defaulted color(which is already black to something else). How could I do that with **CSS** style property??

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
          </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Don’t overwrite bootstrap default classes. Add you own and give them new style.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create your own styles to override Bootstraps if you load your rules after Bootstraps are loaded. If for some reason you have to load your first, then your rules need a higher specificity. Bootstrap's rules for an inverse navbar background color are:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #222;
    border-color: #080808;
}
```

So make your own rule like and load it after Bootstrap's CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #080808;
}
```

If you must load before Bootstrap, incrase your selector's specificity by using a selector like `body .navbar.navbar-inverse`

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/72yRUIanwH)**

Answer (score -1):

bro in bootstrap we have predefined classes , it means that we cannot change the properties in it , we have to use them as they are.
You can try changing it's style attribute in  tag.

Something like this.....

`.navbar-default {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
   }`

Comment: You can **absolutely** override CSS properties.